# Accordion not working in Firefox but works in rest of browsers

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, accordion

Having an issue with a code segment for an accordion in Firefox 51.0.1. Code works in Edge, Chrome, Safari, etc. Not really sure where to go from here. Not really getting anywhere with this. Assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="options_section">
    <div class="options_container">
        <div class="maincontainer">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h3 style="color: white">Text</h3>
                <p style="color: white">Text</p>
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne2">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> <img class="open-arrow" src="assets/white_open_arrow.png"> <img class="down-arrow" src="assets/white_closed_arrow.png">Text</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">Text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> <img class="open-arrow" src="assets/white_open_arrow.png"> <img class="down-arrow" src="assets/white_closed_arrow.png">Text</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                            <div class="panel-body">Text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree2">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> <img class="open-arrow" src="assets/white_open_arrow.png"> <img class="down-arrow" src="assets/white_closed_arrow.png">Text</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                            <div class="panel-body">Text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It'd really helpful if you mention the libraries that you are using

Comment: There might also be some errors in the console, would be nice to list them too.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Gentlemen. Found the issue. Was a bad library. Something I should have caught.